# ListView with TextView autoLink not receiving OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, textview, onitemclicklistener, autolink

My **PostFragment.java** implements **AbsListView.OnItemClickListener**, and I get the 
onItemClick event without a problem on every item, unless there's a link on the TextView: **lblListItem**.
The link on the TextView can be clicked without a problem and open a website, but the background of the list cannot be clicked and so the onItemClick is never called.

Example of a link string: http://www.google.com

I have this TextView on my **list_item.xml**:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        style="@style/TextView.ListItem"
        android:text="Text."
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgUser"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        />
```

I think that this is relevant, on my adapter I have some items that receive:

```
view.setOnClickListener()...
```

How can I make the list item clickable at the same time the link for the website is clickable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root view in your row layout. I've done some testing with this and it seems to work.

Comment: Simple as that, worked like a charm. Thank you kind sir!